# How do I fill the Home Description?

Tags: plugins, seo, headers

For some reason All in One Seo is not putting the text that I put in the Home Description field

if you google, dvdripfreemoviedownloads.com, the first result, which is my homepage should have something else under the Home Description? Anyone know how I can fix this will All in One SEO

If anything I'd like to imput the Home Description manually. I heard that it can be done by inputting that in the header.php, How do I do it manually? below is my header.php

```
    <?php
// Press75.com
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<!--
**********************************************************************************************

Designed and Built by Jason Schuller - theSevenFive.com, Press75.com

CSS, XHTML and Design Files are all Copyright 2007-2010 Circa75 Media, LLC

Be inspired, but please don't steal...

**********************************************************************************************
-->

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <!-- page titles -->
    <title>
    <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('description'); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_search() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Search Results<?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_author() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Author Archives<?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?><?php wp_title(''); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_page() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php wp_title(''); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_category() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php single_cat_title(); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_month() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php the_time('F'); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if (function_exists('is_tag')) { if ( is_tag() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Tag Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php  single_tag_title("", true); } } ?>
    </title>

    <!-- meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <?php if (is_single() || is_page() ) : if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>" />
    <?php endwhile; endif; elseif(is_home()) : ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- import required theme styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css3.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style-ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style-ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- custom theme styles if there are any -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?sf-custom-content=css" />

    <!-- pingback url and favicon link -->
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <?php if (is_singular() && get_option('thread_comments')) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <?php if (get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "analytics_code")) { ?>
        <?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "analytics_code"); ?>
    <?php } ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-inside">
            <?php if (get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "header_ad")) { ?>
            <div id="full-width-ad">
                <?php echo ($header_ad = get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'header_ad')); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <div id="header-left">
            <?php if (get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "logo_txt")) : ?>
                <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/" title="Home" ><?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "logo_txt"); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/" title="Home" ><img class="fade" src="<?php echo ($logo = get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'logo_img')) ? $logo : get_bloginfo("template_url") . "/images/logo.png"; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <!-- header-left -->

            <div id="header-right">
                <div id="site-search">
                    <?php include('searchform.php'); ?>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- header-right -->
        </div> <!-- header-inside -->
    </div> <!-- header -->  

    <div id="navigation">
        <div class="navigation-inside<?php if (is_home()){echo ' navigation-video';}?><?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed", true) || get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed_manual", true)){echo ' navigation-video';}?><?php if (is_category()){echo ' navigation-category';}?>">
            <?php if (get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "menu_management")) : ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header')); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li <?php if (is_home()) { echo 'class=""'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/" title="Home">Home</a></li>

                <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>

                <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>

                <li class="subscribe"><a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="Subscribe via RSS">Subscribe</a></li>

                <?php if (get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "twitter_link")) { ?>
                <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . "twitter_link"); ?>" title="Twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div> <!-- navigation-inside -->
    </div>  <!-- navigation -->
```

---

Yes I know where the Home Description goes in All in one seo. I've used it on my other sites but there's something up with this theme I think

But can someone tell me how to input this manually in the header.php please?

Comment: Did you put the home description into the main All-in-One settings page, or on the specific page you've set as your home page? It must be in the main AIO settings page or it won't show up.

Comment: Yes I know where the Home Description goes in All in one seo. I've used it on my other sites but there's something up with this theme I think

But can someone tell me how to input this manually in the header.php please?

Answer (score 1):

Is this all you need?  You're header is already using this function for the meta-desc, but maybe you're homepage is different than your blog main archive.

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="I'll take swords for 200." /> 
<?php } ?>
```

Use `is_home()` for the blog main archive.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that this code in your header.php is overriding the description as fed by AIO SEO:

```
 <!-- meta tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<?php if (is_single() || is_page() ) : if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>" />
<?php endwhile; endif; elseif(is_home()) : ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Specifically that second-to-last line is spitting out the site description (by default "Just another WordPress blog", set in Settings > Default) as a meta tag. Perhaps if you remove it All-in-One will take over and work as expected?

Hope this helps - best of luck!